# Is it possible to get user's likes and comments on posts in a specific page?

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

What I need to get is:

All the comments and likes for the logged-in user on a specific page.

Using the below i can get only the likes on pages.

```
FacebookMobile.api("/me/likes", facebookGetUserLikes, null, "GET");
function facebookGetUserLikes(success:Object,fail:Object):void{
    if(success!=null){
        for(var i:int = 0; i < success.length; i++){
            trace("like.id = ", success[i].id);
            trace("like.name = ", success[i].name);
            trace("like.category = ", success[i].category);
            trace("like.created_time = ", success[i].created_time);
        }
    }
    if(fail!=null)trace("--> facebookGetUserLikes fail = ", fail.toString());
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use FQL for this as it is a complex query. Here is my attempt:

`SELECT user_id, object_id FROM like WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id = PAGEID) AND user_id = USERID`

I've just tested this with a page that I liked something on and it works.

Comment: What about the comments? @Matthew Johnston
I have tried to access the comments table with no success, I'm new in databases and queries
Thanks for your help
Cheers